# Excel VBA, if run time of macro is greater than 5 minutes stop running code automatically

Tags: excel, vba

I have a solver add on installed into Excel that I have created another macro with. When I run the macro with the solver, once it gets to the solver portion, the macro continuously runs. I don't need solver to solve it perfectly (could sometimes take over an hour+) I just want solver to run for 5, 10, 15 min etc (whatever I designate it to) and then move on with the macro. I am trying to automate the process so I don't have to click Ctrl+break or escape manually.

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim starter As Date
    starter = Now
    Do


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Application.Run "EikonRefreshWorkbook"
    DoEvents
    
    Sheets("Investing").Select
    
    Worksheets("Historic Top Performers").Range("H3:H12").Copy
    Worksheets("Investing").Range("V212:V221").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                           :=False, Transpose:=False
    Worksheets("Historic Top Performers").Range("J3:J12").Copy
    Worksheets("Investing").Range("W212:W221").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                           :=False, Transpose:=False
    Worksheets("Investing").Range("X212:X221").ClearContents
    Sheets("Investing").Select
    SolverOk SetCell:="$V$227", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$X$212:$X$221" _
             , Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$V$227", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$X$212:$X$221" _
             , Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    Solversolve (True)
    DoEvents
    Worksheets("Investing").Range("X212:X221").Copy
    Worksheets("Investing").Range("AB213:AB222").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                           :=False, Transpose:=False
    Worksheets("Investing").Range("V212:V221").Copy
    Worksheets("Investing").Range("Aa213:Aa222").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                           :=False, Transpose:=False
                           
    Worksheets("Investing").Range("AA213:AB222").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Investing").SORT.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Investing").SORT.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "AA213"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortTextAsNumbers
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Investing").SORT
        .SetRange Range("AA213:AB222")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    
    Sheets("Historic Top Performers").Select
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 

     If DateDiff("s", startTime, Now) > 5 Then
         Exit Do

     End If



End Sub
```

Comment: Easiest way would be to move the `If DateDiff(...` somewhere inside a prominent loop inside the Solver, making the assumption that any `MySolver` that is taking over 5m is looping on something.  Probably not the innermost loop, because it would be too expensive to check everytime.  Perhaps not the outermost loop, as it may not check often enough.  But "somewhere".  The problem with the above is that the `If` wont ever get called until `MySolver` is complete.  If the solver is completely black-box, you could do tricks with the OS and an external file sending the Ctrl-Break keys.

Comment: @User51 Please see my edit to the post. What you suggest is that I put the "If DateDiff(..." right after "Application.ScreenUpdating = False" and then the "End if" at the end of the code next to the other "End if"

Comment: I assume you're missing a `Loop` at the bottom to match the `Do` at the top?  Here's the question... Do you want to abort the `Solversolve` function at 5m, or make sure the whole thing doesn't take more than 5m?  If the former, that's the black box case (assuming you can't see inside of `Solversolve`).  If the latter, if the `Solversolve` itself isn't too long, the above seems reasonable.

Comment: I want to stop solversolve after 5 minutes. So the "Loop" Needs to go before the last "application.ScreenUpdating = True" but still inside both the "End if's". Correct?

Comment: If you want to stop it while it's inside ` Solversolve`, and you don't have any access to that source code, you will likely need an external way to stop it, as an `If` check outside the function wont run until `Solversolve` exists.  Does hitting Ctrl-Break while in `Solversolve` stop the process?

Comment: Ok, say I have a different macro, that doesn't deal with Solver. How would I make that macro stop running if it was running for greater than 5 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
If DateDiff("s", starter, Now) > 5 Then Exit Do
or
If Now - starter > 5 Then Exit Do
```

Comment: Where would I put the "Do", "With", "End" and "theMacro" with you answer? I am having a problem with figuring out where to put everything to make this "Do" code work. Thanks

Comment: You can put code inside any loop you know it take long time and you can put it more than one in your macro